# collecting google analytics data on localhost

Tags: google-analytics

According to the [Google Analytics docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains) if you want to collect analytics data when running an app on localhost you should replace

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

with

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'none');
```

When using the latter, will analytics data also be collected on "normal" domains, e.g. www.example.com, or will it *only* work on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You should pretty much always be using `auto`, even when running on localhost. The section you linked to in the docs was written prior to the `auto` feature (automatic cookie domain configuration) being added to analytics.js

You can confirm that `auto` works on regular domains as well as on localhost by using your developer tools to see that a `_ga` cookie is successfully written.